# Running Spark Unit Tests in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have a spark job I'm developing in IntelliJ. It's builds via maven, the tests pass, and I can run the job locally. However, If I try to run the tests via IntelliJ, I get

> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in
>   SparkContext.class refers to term akka in package root which is not
>   available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or
>   the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version
>   used when compiling SparkContext.class.

Comment: Are you making a fat jar out of your maven project? If not error clearly says, there is either library conflict or library missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just busting and rebuilding the IMLs in IntelliJ and this fixed the issue.